# How can I get notifications a worker finished processing in bull, express

Tags: node.js, express

I set up a bull/redis queue in my express project:

count_to_ten.js:

```
module.exports = function(queue) {
  console.log('Preparing Job: count to ten');

  queue.process(function(job, done) {
    console.log('Starting job: ' + job.data.name)
    for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
      console.log('Index: ' + i);
    }
    done()
  })
}
```

And I set up the queue like this:

```
  const defaultQueue = new Queue('default', 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379');
  const worker = require('../jobs/count_to_ten')
  worker(defaultQueue)
```

Then I finally try to trigger the background processing from my router/controller:

```
queue.add( { name: 'JohnDoe' } )
```

Which seems to work fine, I see the logs counting to ten, and I assume it is running on the background as it is not hanging my request (I am using nodemon)

However, I never get to see a completed callback (I added this to my routes file, after I call add):

```
queue.on('completed', function(job, result) {
  console.log(`Job ${job.id} completed`);
});
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

EDIT: I am not really sure anymore if the processing is happening in the background by now. Should I have a separate daemon for the background process?